# Index search: trade accuracy for performance

Tags: python, performance, numpy, search

I have a simple two lines block of code that adds values to an array according to the closest elements found in another array. Since it is buried deep inside an MCMC it is executed millions of times, and I need it to be as efficient as possible.

The code below works and it is pretty self explanatory. Basically: the array `arr2[0]` (the one used to find the closest elements in `arr0`) contains values in the range `(10., 25.)`. Currently I look for the *absolute closest* element in `arr0` for each element in `arr2[0`] using [np.searchsorted()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html), taking advantage of the fact that `arr0` is already sorted.

**I would be willing to trade some accuracy for better performance**. That is, I could live with an index that points to a "close" element with a tolerance of say `+-0.2`, instead of the *absolute closest* element (which is what I do now)

Can this be done? More importantly: can this be done and **improve the performance** of the code?

```
import numpy as np

# Random initial data with the actual shapes used by my code.
Nmax = 1000000
arr0 = np.linspace(5., 30., Nmax)
D = np.random.randint(2, 4)
arr1 = np.random.uniform(-3., 3., (D, Nmax))
arr2 = np.random.uniform(10., 25., (10, 1500))

# Can these two lines be made faster?
# Indexes of elements in 'arr0' closest to the elements in 'arr2[0]'
closest_idxs = np.searchsorted(arr0, arr2[0])
# Add elements from 'arr1' to the first dimensions of 'arr2', according
# to the indexes found above.
arr_final = arr2[:arr1.shape[0]] + arr1[:, closest_idxs]
```

Comment: Your code doesn't run that slowly

Comment: @QuangHoang I know, but it eats up ~20% of my MCMC run and I'd like to improve that if possible.

Comment: I'm curious, if you say tolerance is `+/- 0.2`, doesn't it reduce the `Nmax` significantly?

Comment: It does. I could achieve that by lowering `Nmax` to ~200, but I was after a solution that didn't involve (if possible) modifying that value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an approximate matching with given tolerance value, we can use it to reduce the first arg to `searchsorted` and hence optimize, like so -

```
tol = 0.2 # tolerance value
s = int(np.round(tol/(arr0[1]-arr0[0])))
i = np.searchsorted(arr0[::s], arr2[0])
i -= (arr0[i*s]-arr2[0])>tol/2
closest_idxs_out = i*s
```

Timings on given setup -

```
In [123]: %%timeit
     ...: closest_idxs = np.searchsorted(arr0, arr2[0])
     ...: arr_final = arr2[:arr1.shape[0]] + arr1[:, closest_idxs]
1000 loops, best of 3: 641 µs per loop

In [125]: %%timeit
     ...: tol = 0.2 # tolerance value
     ...: s = int(np.round(tol/(arr0[1]-arr0[0])))
     ...: i = np.searchsorted(arr0[::s], arr2[0])
     ...: i -= (arr0[i*s]-arr2[0])>tol/2
     ...: closest_idxs_out = i*s
10000 loops, best of 3: 63.2 µs per loop
```

Comment: This fails with `TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method`. Does it work in your case Divakar?

Comment: @Gabriel You are using the correct `s` with integer value I hope. In your case, with that error msg it seems `s` is not an int. But, I am pushing it as `int` with `s = int(..)`. Can you run again?

Comment: My bad, I was re-defining `s` as `s=t.time()`, sorry!